# Server 2012 R2: Unable to manage Remote Workgroup Joined Server

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, active-directory

So here's my environment:

I am running Hyper-V on my Windows 10 Host, and I have 2 Windows Server 2012 R2 Servers running on it.

Corp-DC1
Local-DC1
Corp-DC1 is the PDC of the x.Corp domain and Forest. I am attempting to join Local-DC1 as the PDC of the x.Local domain to the existing Forest, however, I am at my final breathe.

I have DNS setup like so:

On Corp-DC1, I have a zone named x.local and inside this zone, I have my Local-DC1 A record created (IP address 192.168.3.1). I also have the reverse lookup zone created and configured properly. The SOA and NS are both 'Local-DC1.x.Local'

On Local-DC1, I have the exact same thing configured for x.corp. I also manually configured the DNS Prefix to be x.local, so that the zone lookups would work.

My routing is configured correctly, as I can ping each servers IP address without a problem, however, I cannot resolve by hostname, therefore, I cannot manage Local-DC1 from Corp-DC1 in order to install ADDS.

The actual error messages I get when attempting to add the server to Server Manager on Corp-DC1 are: "Refresh Failed with the Following error: The RPC Server is unavailable." and "Configuration refresh failed with the following error: The metadata failed to be retrieved from the server, due to the following error: The WinRM client cannot process the request because the server name cannot be resolved.

I think that about covers where I'm at. I cannot figure out why the servers can't find the Host records...

Any advice?

Comment: Windows 10 host with 2 VMs, Corp and Local, and they can ping but not RPC? I would do a network trace from both sides. In lieu of that, what is the hyper-v switch connection type?  Also, what is the DNS server listed for both VMs?

Answer (score 0):

For domain joined hosts there is a lot more stuff in DNS than just the hosts name. Just point the DNS from all machines to the one, that hosts the domain zone (or use a forwarder to to so). In the domains firs DNS you will see some more zones (and entries), stuff like "_msdcs" and "_tcp". Those are required to provide resolution to AD service endpoints (which seems to be not the case in your question).

Always remember: "managing" (aka 'connecting') is not the same as "Join the domain as an DC to provide services".

Additionally, the most common error for 'RPC Server is unavailable' is a firewall somewhere. Just check both machines (and your routing) for that.